# how to convert a file from data to ASCII format

Tags: file-conversion

I have the file /etc/mydata which is in data format

$ file /etc/mydata
/etc/mydata: data

is there any fast way to convert

/etc/mydata: data

from data format to ASCII format to have this

/etc/mydata: ASCII text

thank you!
thank you

Comment: Data can mean anything... What kind of data is it? What format?

Comment: What does "data format" mean?

Comment: the file contains this
^@^@^@^@^12.81.1.12
I would remove those ^@^@^@^@^ converting the file to ASCII (removing all non ASCII chars)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strings` will filter any ASCII text in the file. But it's probably not what you actually need.